# What is the formula for calculating load factor of hash table when collisions are handled by many different techniques?

Tags: hash-function

I am in a rush to submit some assignment, may I have the formula for calculating the load factor of hash tables when collisions are handled by linear probing, quadratic probing and double hashing? I understand that for separate chaining the formula will be number of items in array/ array size